# updating asp.net grid view with vb.net using left join

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Hi I have two tables for eg

**Table 1**

```
item  rawno   name
------------------
1          0      egg
2       1      bread
3       0      rice
4       0      dal
5       1      milk
```

**Table 2**

```
item   rawno    name   transno  storeno  ordunits ordcases del_data
---------------------------------------------------------------------
1      0         egg     12      1        12      1         2nd jan
3      0         rice    13      2        23      2         2nd jan
```

Using `GridView` and `left join` i got resulting table as

```
item   rawno    name   transno  storeno  ordunits ordcases del_data
---------------------------------------------------------------------
1      0         egg     12      1        12      1         2nd jan
3      0         rice    13      2        23      2         2nd jan
```

Result table in `GridView`:

```
item   rawno    name   transno  storeno  ordunits ordcases del_data
---------------------------------------------------------------------
1      0         egg     12      1        12      1         2nd jan
2      1         egg         
3      0         rice    13      2        23      2         2nd jan
4      0         dal                                               
5      1         milk
```

I got above table using `left join`. Now in the output `GridView` i should able to edit all the fields from `table 2`. But i am unable to do that,
eventhough i can edit it in `GridView` it is not saving in the database. Kindly help me on this

Answer (score 0):

you can rather use a button and textboxes to display the data of grid view in textbox and then change the values in textbox and submit it to add to database

Comment: yes I have already added button and editing it in grid view.But after submitting the button I am not getting the updated value in gridview and my database is not updating.

Comment: show the code of click event of submit button. then probably the problem can be figured out

Comment: Sorry there is no code for button click I just configured data source in grid view.Below are the queries for select and update.SELECT sample.matno, invorder.strno, invorder.transno, sample.rawpkgno, invorder.ordunits, invorder.ordcases, invorder.punits, invorder.deldate, invorder.pcases, sample.material FROM (sample LEFT OUTER JOIN invorder ON invorder.matno = sample.matno) WHERE (invorder.deldate=?) AND (invorder.strno=?) OR ([invorder.deldate] IS NULL) and UPDATE invorder SET ordunits= ?,ordcases=?,pcases=?,punits=?,deldate=?,material=? WHERE(strno=?)AND(matno=?)AND(transno=?)AND(rawpkgno=?)

Comment: Following are the invorder and sample respectivelytables.invorder:strno(Primary),transno(Primary),matno(Primary),rawpkgno(Primary),ordunits,ordcases,pcases,punits,deldate,material and for sample matno(primary),rawpkgno(primary),material

Comment: i am asking you to display the code of submit button so that i can check if there is any mistake in the code due to which the data is not updated in database and hence not in grid view as well